# Create sub-tree in json in scala

Tags: json, scala

Im using scala.util.parsing.json and I want to create a json with the following format:

```
{ users : { 
    username: foo,
    password: bar}
}
```

I tried using this code:

```
 val json = JSONObject(
  Map(
    "users" -> Map(
      "username" -> "foo",
      "password" -> "bar")))
```

but this method create this json:

```
{"user" : Map(username -> foo, password -> bar)}
```

thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
val json = JSONObject(
           Map("users" -> JSONObject(Map(
               "username" -> "foo",
                "password" -> "bar"))))
```

seems to do it.